# SSIS insert a large number of rows if not existing?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to do "insert/delete if not exists" for many very big tables from Server A to B. The lookup component doesn't work well because it issues one query for each row to check if the row exist in the destination database table.

What's the good option?

---

The tables all have PK but they may have the size of several hundred GB individually. The destination tables may only miss under 3% rows. So merge component may not be a good option?

Comment: well regardless if you use `insert where someColumn not in (select anotherColumn from anotherTable)` or `MERGE()` or some other validation method--you still want to check if the record exists... so the check is going to have to be done in one way or another regardless, no?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you are working with?

Comment: If you do have primary keys, you can use a merge join (full join) and then do a conditional split based on if the PK of table 2 is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the merge SSIS component.  I personally found better performance by loading all data to a staging table and running the Merge T-sql statement afterwards in a stored procedure.

Comment: I updated the question for more information. It seem neither merge component nor staging tables is a good option?

Comment: t-sql merge command performs very well.  I do not think any other process will perform as well no matter how many matches you expect to find.

Comment: Does T-sql merge work well on big linked server table?